# Powershell Convert integer to guid

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert an integer (or a number in strings) into guid via powershell, I've used following and can't find another way. is it possible at all?

```
$myId = [System.Guid]::Parse("123456789")

Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)."
```

same happens when I do it without quotes, number only in parse function.

Comment: it is a legit question, care to explain the downvote?

Comment: The error is explaining why this isn't working, and telling you what it is expecting. You can't just parse any random number or string as a GUID. [Check out the documentation for more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Doesn't this greatly reduce the odds of coming up with a *globally unique* identifier? What's the compelling reason to avoid using `New-Guid`?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' That is because I need specifically a certain ID's GUID. It's not something I can change. I'm unfortunately not allowed to give specifics. But got my answer anyways, thanks.

Comment: A GUID has structure. See [RFC 4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. A [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is 128 bit value and *way* larger than ordinary integer. The [parse method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a well-formed input.

To convert integer into guid, try and add leading zeroes. Like so,

```
[System.Guid]::Parse("0"*23 + "123456789")

Guid
----
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000123456789
```

Comment: A GUID or UUID is not just any 128-bit value. [A GUID has structure](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122). "The variant field determines the layout of the UUID.  That is, the interpretation of all other bits in the UUID depends on the setting of the bits in the variant field."

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$myId = [System.Guid]::Parse("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123")
$myId | gm
TypeName: System.Guid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more dynamic way to do it that takes into account the length of the string representing the integer

```
$foo = 123456
[System.Guid]::Parse("0"*(32-$foo.ToString().Length) + $foo.ToString())
```